Spring Batch My Command Line Runner implementation is being called intermittently
I have my custom command line runner implementation which add a job parameter in run method. I'm invoking my spring task from a SCDF task scheduler. The problem is my commandlinerunner run is not not executed sometimes so, the parameter is not passed leading to my failure of my job. My question is Why is my custome commandlinerunner not getting executed all the times? Will there be any default commandline runner that take precedence over custom command line and won't let the custom command line runner execute?
@Component
 public class TaskRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
private final Job myJob;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskRunner.class);

public TaskRunner(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job myJob){
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    this.myJob = myJob;
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    String currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
    LOGGER.info("Current Date Time is {}", currentDateTime);
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("RUNTIMESTAMP", currentDateTime)
        .toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(myJob, jobParameters);
}

}

Difficult to answer your question without more context. Why do you need a custom runner to only add a job parameter in the run method? Can't you pass the parameter to the cli or api when you launch the job? Please share the code and how you run the job to be able to help you efficiently.

I want to pass the current date time as a job parameter when running it as a task from SCDF scheduling Agent.  I couldn't find a way to pass it from SCDF shell. So I had to add a command line runner implementation and pass the argument. Adding my Code as well as part of the question

Why is my custome commandlinerunner not getting executed all the times? That should not be the case. Is the schedule too frequent (for example are you running a job instance every few milliseconds)?
